# android popup windows

Tags: java, android

i want to create in my app a popup window with enter text field and ok and cancel buttons:

this is my code in MainActivity:

```
forgotPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    View pview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.forgot_password_popup,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.layout.login));

                    final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.forgot_password_popup,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.layout.login)));
                    pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.LEFT,0,0);
                    pw.update(8,-70,150,270);

                    //if onclick written here, it gives null pointer exception.
                    Button okbtn=(Button)pview.findViewById(R.id.okbtn);
                    Button cancelbtn = (Button)pview.findViewById(R.id.cancelbtn);
                    final EditText emailText = (EditText) pview.findViewById(R.id.EmailText);
                    okbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            try {
                                ParseUser.requestPasswordReset(emailText.getText().toString());
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    cancelbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            pw.dismiss();

                        }
                });

                }
            });
```

and here is my forgot password_popup.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/EmailText"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
         android:hint="Enter Email Address"
         android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
         android:password="true"
         android:singleLine="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/okbtn"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="OK" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

however it cut off (i cant see the text field or the cancel button, also, there is no any background to the popup windows (i want a transparent background)

and also, i cant click on the ok button, so something wrong with my code

i will be glad for help

this is how  it looks like:

http://img827.imageshack.us/img827/9545/capturehdv.png

thanks alot

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: thanks, i will look at it, also, do you know how to create it trasperanct? thanks

Comment: @AdirRahamim Do you try what I have posted..?

Comment: also, i didnt understand from android developer, how do i start the alert dialog? creating a new intent and startActivity? or there is something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is Take a tranparent image and set it as background for your popup layout.

And also try

```
android:background=@null
```

Comment: @null should be in quotes. Best solution is create a transparent image in photoshop or any photoeditor and set it as a Background for your popup parent layout